# Using calc library with background package

Tags: calculations, backgrounds, tikz-calc

Im trying to place a page border on every page using ornaments and the background package. I'd like to place this frame 0.6cm away from the border of the page and therefore I'm using the calc library of tikz to specify the position of the frame for each page based on coordinates. Even though the document is compiled with XeLaTeX and the frame is placed correctly -I guess- I get the error:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named {current page.north west} + {0.6cm,-0.6cm}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\xoffset{0.6cm}
\def\yoffset{0.6cm}
\def\ornament{61}
\def\ornamentcolor{black}

%Command for inserting the frames
\newcommand{\pageframe}{

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, inner sep=0pt]
      %Necessary coordinates
      \coordinate (UR) at ($(current page.north east) + (-\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (UL) at ($(current page.north west) + (\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LR) at ($(current page.south east) + (-\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LL) at ($(current page.south west) + (\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (CL) at ($(current page.west) + (\xoffset,0)$);
      \coordinate (CR) at ($(current page.east) + (-\xoffset,0)$);

      %Ornaments located at the corners of the page
      \node[anchor=north west] (ULCorner) at (UL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=north east] (URCorner) at (UR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=v ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south east] (LRCorner) at (LR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=c ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south west] (LLCorner) at (LL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=h ]{\ornament}};%

      %Ornaments between the corners: Calculates the distance between the 2 upper corners and uses it for the width of the bar ornament.
      \path (CL) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=-3pt] (CLBar) at (CL){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \path (CR) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=0pt] (CRBar) at (CR){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CLBar.east) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(ULCorner.south west) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CRBar.east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$) to ($(URCorner.south east) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CLBar.west) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(LLCorner.north west) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CRBar.west) + (0.8pt,1)$) to ($(LRCorner.north east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};

      %Ornaments between he corners: Top and bottom.
       \path[] (ULCorner.north east) to [ornament=88, color=black] (URCorner.north west) {};
       \path (LRCorner.south west) to [ornament=88,color=black] (LLCorner.south east) {};

  \end{tikzpicture}}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,color=black,opacity=1,contents=\pageframe,  angle=0,position={{(current page.north west)} + {(\xoffset,-\yoffset)}},nodeanchor=north west}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

My question is: What I'm doing wrong? Does the background package accept this type of expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution saves ~20 kB per page and some compilation time, using package `xsavebox`.

Open on [**Overleaf**](https://v2.overleaf.com/read/wdrxpqjzzqpt).

16,345 B for 1 page of lipsum,

19,831 B for 2 pages of lipsum,

36,361 B for 10 pages of lipsum (`xelatex`)

**Edit:**
The code was further optimized for file size and graphical precision. The corner ornament and the "bar ornament" were saved in `xsaveboxes` for re-use at various locations. Moreover, the lines of the "bar ornament" were sampled in order to later extend the "bar ornaments" on the left and right page edges.

Works with all engines/backends, including `dvips`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%some size calculations
\def\xoffset{0.6cm}
\def\yoffset{0.6cm}
\def\cornerOrnamentWidth{2cm}
\edef\barOrnamentWidth{\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-\xoffset*2-\cornerOrnamentWidth*2\relax}

\def\cornerOrnament{61}
\def\barOrnament{88}

\def\ornamentcolor{black}

% This saves the whole ornament frame once in an xsavebox.
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xsbox{OrnamentCorner}{\pgfornament[width = \cornerOrnamentWidth, color = \ornamentcolor]{\cornerOrnament}}%  
  \xsbox{OrnamentBar}{\pgfornament[width=\barOrnamentWidth, color = \ornamentcolor]{\barOrnament}}%  
  \xsbox{LineSample}{\makebox[2.5cm][r]{\theOrnamentBar}}%
  \xsbox{OrnamentBox}{%  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, x=\paperwidth,y=\paperheight]
      \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

      % necessary coordinates
      \coordinate (UR) at ($(1,1) + (-\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (UL) at ($(0,1) + (\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LR) at ($(1,0) + (-\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LL) at ($(0,0) + (\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (CL) at ($(0,0.5) + (\xoffset,0)$);
      \coordinate (CR) at ($(1,0.5) + (-\xoffset,0)$);

      % ornaments located at page corners
      \node[anchor=north west] (ULCorner) at (UL){\theOrnamentCorner};%
      \node[anchor=north west,xscale=-1] (URCorner) at (UR) {\theOrnamentCorner};%
      \node[anchor=north west, scale=-1] (LRCorner) at (LR){\theOrnamentCorner};%
      \node[anchor=north west,yscale=-1] (LLCorner) at (LL){\theOrnamentCorner};%

      % ornaments on the left and right sides
      \node [rotate=90,anchor=center] at (CL) {\theOrnamentBar};
      \node [rotate=90,anchor=east] at (ULCorner.south west) {\theLineSample\theLineSample};
      \node [rotate=90,anchor=east,xscale=-1] at (LLCorner.south west) {\theLineSample\theLineSample};

      \node [rotate=90,anchor=center,scale=-1] at (CR) {\theOrnamentBar};
      \node [rotate=90,anchor=east, yscale=-1] at (URCorner.south west) {\theLineSample\theLineSample};
      \node [rotate=90,anchor=east,  scale=-1] at (LRCorner.south west) {\theLineSample\theLineSample};

      % ornaments at top and bottom page edges
      \path (ULCorner.north east) to node {\theOrnamentBar} (URCorner.north east) {};
      \path (LRCorner.north east) to node [scale=-1] {\theOrnamentBar} (LLCorner.north east) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

% This adds the frame (a reference, actually) on every page.
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\theOrnamentBox}%  

\begin{document}
% \lipsum[1,2] 
 \lipsum[1-5] 
% \lipsum[1-28] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works really good, but it still has some problems depending on the compiler selected. With LaTeX (DVI), the frame is not placed correctly. With LuaLaTeX, there are no problems, with the exception of this strange error message that says: "[LuaLaTeX] finished with exit code 1". With PDFLaTeX as well as with XeLaTeX, there are absolutely NO errors or problems. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Charlie : For me, the dvips route perfectly works. See my example on [Overleaf](https://v2.overleaf.com/read/wdrxpqjzzqpt), configured to use LaTeX+dvips+ps2pdf compiler. And also no error with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Charlie :  The code was further optimized.

Comment: I'm starting to think that these error messages have something to do with Kile 3 beta. I have actually been having some other issues that I never had before with other versions of kile. Anyway, Im going to test your code and let you know how it went. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I tested your solution and this is what I got: It works with all compilers, except with LaTeX (DVI). Even though it compiles successfully, this actually produces a bad quality document, which is not very relevant considering I want to produce PDF files. With LuaLaTeX there are no problems at all, but the strange error message: Finished with exit code 1 still appears. This is why I'm starting to think it has to do with the version of Kile I'm using.

Anyway, considering all the answers and the results obtained, I decided to mark your answer as the accepted answer. Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that the editor (Kile) is the reason for the issues you encounter. I supect you are using an outdated TeX installation (some old TeXLive is my guess). Consider installing vanilla TeXLive-2018, and run `tlmgr update --all --self` from time to time.  Also, you are on Linux as you are using Kile. It shouldn't be difficult to run `latex` and friends directly on the command line. I am sure you will get better results then (even on the `dvips` route) .

Comment: I'm using texlive from Debian buster. I don't think is outdated...

Comment: Seems to be reasonably recent. And what about running `lualatex` or `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` on the command line?

Answer (score 5):

**SOLUTION THAT SEEMS TO WORK WITH ALL COMPILERS**. One actually does not really need `backgrounds` here. `eso-pic`/`atbegshi` will do.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\xoffset{0.6cm}
\def\yoffset{0.6cm}
\def\ornament{61}
\def\ornamentcolor{black}

%Command for inserting the frames
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, inner sep=0pt]
      %Necessary coordinates
      \coordinate (UR) at ($(current page.north east) + (-\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (UL) at ($(current page.north west) + (\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LR) at ($(current page.south east) + (-\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LL) at ($(current page.south west) + (\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (CL) at ($(current page.west) + (\xoffset,0)$);
      \coordinate (CR) at ($(current page.east) + (-\xoffset,0)$);

      %Ornaments located at the corners of the page
      \node[anchor=north west] (ULCorner) at (UL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=north east] (URCorner) at (UR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=v ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south east] (LRCorner) at (LR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=c ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south west] (LLCorner) at (LL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=h ]{\ornament}};%

      %Ornaments between the corners: Calculates the distance between the 2 upper corners and uses it for the width of the bar ornament.
      \path (CL) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=-3pt] (CLBar) at (CL){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \path (CR) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=0pt] (CRBar) at (CR){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CLBar.east) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(ULCorner.south west) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CRBar.east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$) to ($(URCorner.south east) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CLBar.west) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(LLCorner.north west) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CRBar.west) + (0.8pt,1)$) to ($(LRCorner.north east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};

      %Ornaments between he corners: Top and bottom.
       \path[] (ULCorner.north east) to [ornament=88, color=black] (URCorner.north west) {};
       \path (LRCorner.south west) to [ornament=88,color=black] (LLCorner.south east) {};

  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

I have checked that this works fine with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`. A sample output is shown below. It does *not* seem to work with `latex -> dvi -> pdf`, however, this is probably something one can live with in 2018.

**OLD ANSWER**. **DISCLAIMER**: I have not carefully read the manual for backgrounds. A quick search of `xelatex` does not produce a hit, but it might well be tat I am missing some basic things. You position the picture anyway with overlay. It will always end up at the same place, regardless of your choice for `position`. **(THIS IS NOT TRUE! THERE ARE COMPILER-DEPENDENT ISSUES THAT I DID NOT EXPECT TO EXIST WHEN WRITING THIS.)**

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\xoffset{0.6cm}
\def\yoffset{0.6cm}
\def\ornament{61}
\def\ornamentcolor{black}

%Command for inserting the frames
\newcommand{\pageframe}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, inner sep=0pt]
      %Necessary coordinates
      \coordinate (UR) at ($(current page.north east) + (-\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (UL) at ($(current page.north west) + (\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LR) at ($(current page.south east) + (-\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LL) at ($(current page.south west) + (\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (CL) at ($(current page.west) + (\xoffset,0)$);
      \coordinate (CR) at ($(current page.east) + (-\xoffset,0)$);

      %Ornaments located at the corners of the page
      \node[anchor=north west] (ULCorner) at (UL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=north east] (URCorner) at (UR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=v ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south east] (LRCorner) at (LR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=c ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south west] (LLCorner) at (LL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=h ]{\ornament}};%

      %Ornaments between the corners: Calculates the distance between the 2 upper corners and uses it for the width of the bar ornament.
      \path (CL) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=-3pt] (CLBar) at (CL){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \path (CR) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=0pt] (CRBar) at (CR){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CLBar.east) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(ULCorner.south west) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CRBar.east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$) to ($(URCorner.south east) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CLBar.west) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(LLCorner.north west) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CRBar.west) + (0.8pt,1)$) to ($(LRCorner.north east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};

      %Ornaments between he corners: Top and bottom.
       \path[] (ULCorner.north east) to [ornament=88, color=black] (URCorner.north west) {};
       \path (LRCorner.south west) to [ornament=88,color=black] (LLCorner.south east) {};

  \end{tikzpicture}}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,color=black,opacity=1,contents=\pageframe, angle=0}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, beautifully positioned ornaments. Simply because `overlay` pics in which you use some absolute page coordinates do not care about the `position` you assign to them.

**ADDENDUM**: This seems to be one of the meanwhile rarer cases in which it matters which compiler one uses. To simplify issues, I removed all position information from `\backgroundsetup`.

> The first surprise is that the `angle` seems to matter. To me this is *very* surprising. This problem seems to be independent of the compiler.

Then the next surprise is that the result depends on the compiler. If I keep `angle=0` in the above, the code works fine as long as I compile with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`.

> However, if I compile with `xelatex`, I do reproduce the issues reported by Charlie. In this case, [Charlie's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451445/121799) seems to be the way to go. If I compile with latex and then convert the `dvi` file to pdf, there is no ornament at all. Altogether I do not think that this question is completely solved. Yet I would like to argue that, in this case, a switch to `eso-pic` resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, it doesn't work as you describe. I followed your answer, but the frame is actually shifted to the left and the right side of the frame crosses down the text from top to bottom. This can be a system-specific issue, but I'm not sure.

In rigor, there's no problem. The document is generated and no compilation errors arise, but tikz complaints because of this expression inside \backgroundsetup.

Comment: @Charlie Not on my TeXLive 2018 distribution. I compile with pdflatex. Notice that you have to compile 3 times. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I compiled the document several times with the same effect.

Comment: @Charlie To me this is very surprising. What kind of TeX installation do you have? Did you update it recently? My above screen shot is from the above document.

Comment: I found the solution: I removed the overlay and remember pictures in \tikzpicture and specified the position as current page. center with anchor center. This places the frame as expected and no errors arise.

I'm using Debian Buster updated today and I have installed texlive from the repositories.

Comment: @Charlie Glad that you found your own solution but I am very surprised that your solution works, I mean absolute page coordinates without `overlay,remember picture`, and that my code does not work *on your machine*. This is actually worrisome as it means Ti*k*Z may be less predictive than I thought.

Comment: @Charlie Update: my statements are all correct *if* one compiles with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`. If one compiles with `xelatex`, it is true what you say: the ornament gets shifted. If one compiles with `latex -> dvi -> pdf`, there is not even an ornament. Since I know that (a) there are other issues with `xelatex` e.g. in the context of the previous version of `shadows.blur` as well as `datavisualization`, I tend to blame this on `xelatex`. So let me ask again: which compiler do you use?

Comment: Actually, xelatex :( The problem is Im using fontspec (doesn't appear on MWE ) and that won't work with pdflatex.

Comment: @Charlie How about lualatex?

Comment: It works, but like you said, but it shows: "[LuaLaTeX] Finished with exit code 1." Looking at the output it gives the following message: "Unable to read environment locale: exit now."

Comment: @Charlie I added a second solution, using eso-pic, that works fine with `xelatex`.

Comment: I test your updated answer tomorrow and tell you how it went. Thanks for your time! Maybe the maintainer of the background package could give us some insights about these issues.

Comment: Hi Marmot, I have tested your updated code so here is what I got: 1.- Using LaTeX (DVI), there is a huge frame shift. The upper part of the frame crosses the text from left to right and on the 1st page there is no frame at all. 2.- With LuaLaTeX works, but it gives the message: Finished with exit code 1. Also, the first page has no frame at all. 3.- PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX do the job with no error messages, but again the first page has no frame.

Comment: @Charlie I changed the command. Maybe it works now. I am confused about your eit code thing.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestions of @Marmot, I removed the overlay and remember picture flags within the tikzpicture environment, set the position to current position.center with anchor set also to center. This works when compiling with XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\xoffset{0.6cm}
\def\yoffset{0.6cm}
\def\ornament{61}
\def\ornamentcolor{black}

%Command for inserting the frames
\newcommand{\pageframe}{

  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
      %Necessary coordinates
      \coordinate (UR) at ($(current page.north east) + (-\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (UL) at ($(current page.north west) + (\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LR) at ($(current page.south east) + (-\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LL) at ($(current page.south west) + (\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (CL) at ($(current page.west) + (\xoffset,0)$);
      \coordinate (CR) at ($(current page.east) + (-\xoffset,0)$);

      %Ornaments located at the corners of the page
      \node[anchor=north west] (ULCorner) at (UL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=north east] (URCorner) at (UR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=v ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south east] (LRCorner) at (LR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=c ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south west] (LLCorner) at (LL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=h ]{\ornament}};%

      %Ornaments between the corners: Calculates the distance between the 2 upper corners and uses it for the width of the bar ornament.
      \path (CL) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=-3pt] (CLBar) at (CL){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \path (CR) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=0pt] (CRBar) at (CR){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CLBar.east) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(ULCorner.south west) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CRBar.east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$) to ($(URCorner.south east) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CLBar.west) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(LLCorner.north west) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,black]($(CRBar.west) + (0.8pt,1)$) to ($(LRCorner.north east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};



      %Ornaments between he corners: Top and bottom.
       \path[] (ULCorner.north east) to [ornament=88, color=black] (URCorner.north west) {};
       \path (LRCorner.south west) to [ornament=88,color=black] (LLCorner.south east) {};

  \end{tikzpicture}}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,color=black,opacity=1,contents=\pageframe, angle=0,
position={current page.center},nodeanchor=center}


\begin{document}

 \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```